# Platform-independent detection of arrow key press in C++

Tags: c++, user-input

In a C++ console program, I've found how to detect and arrow key on Windows, and I've found a lot of other stuff that had nothing to do with the question (despite what I thought were good search terms), but I want to know if there is a platform-independent way to detect an arrow key press.  A decent second place for this would be how to detect arrow key press in unix and mac.  Code fragments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no cross platform way to do it because it's not defined by either C or C++ standards (though there may be libraries which abstract away the differences when compiled on different platforms).

I believe the library you are looking for on POSIX boxes is [curses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html), but I've never used it myself -- I could be wrong.

Keep in mind that it's entirely possible the console program (i.e. `gnome-terminal` or `konsole` or `xterm`) has monopolized the use of those keys for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

As Billy said, there is no standard cross-platform way to do it.

Personally I use this (game-oriented) library for all inputs, cross-platform win/linux/mac : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/

Comment: Project moved to Github: https://github.com/wgois/OIS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this cross-platform by using [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org).

Example code:

```
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>

    int main()
    {
        SDL_Event event;

        SDL_PollEvent(&event);

        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            // Move centerpoint of rotation for one of the trees:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    // do something
                    return 0;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I'm running this on ubuntu 18.04 and it doesn't compile... `undefined reference to \`SDL_PollEvent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`  
What am I doing wrong?? I literally just copied this code and downloaded the library...

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon if it's an undefined reference you're not linking to the libraries properly - look into SDL documentation, SDL tutorials and what you have to link to, and in what order, on your OS/compiler.

Comment: It will only work if you focus the sdl window

Comment: @answer42 That's certainly intended behaviour. You wouldn't want the SDL app to steal keypresses when it's not the focussed window.
Unless you meant something else

Comment: @metamorphosis The question was about a "console program"

Comment: @answer42 That's not relevant.